# Mantel clock frame finish repair

Tags: staining, finishing

I have a mantel clock which had mildew damage. I been working on getting mildew off. To restore it to its original color as seen in right part of frame below, would I need to sand and stain it? I know linseed oil was used on it when it was built about 30 plus years ago. [image]

Comment: What type of wood is the clock made of? If walnut straight linseed oil will probably bring it back but if oak it may need a stain once sanded. I would try cleaning with a fine sandpaper or steel wool trying not to go through the stain because it will be difficult to match.

Comment: I was told the wood was black walnut. When you say straight linseed oil, do you mean boiled linseed oil? What grit sandpaper and what grade steel wool?

Comment: Yes on the boiled linseed, I would use fine steel wool or 400 grit paper since the wood color is natural it should not change much but there is always a slight color change even with natural finishes.

Comment: So I should sand/ use steel wool on mold/damaged finish area and then coat with linseed? How many coats of linseed oil?